# Series expansion of \$ln(5-x)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Series expansion of $\ln(5-x)$

Hey guys, I've been trying to figure out what the series expansion is of this forever and have gotten tunnel vision. Can somebody walk me through the steps? I'd appreciate multiple perspectives if possible. Thanks!!

I know the series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and so I was thinking using that form and integrating or something... but I'm confused...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$ \ln(5 - x) = \ln \left(5 \left(1 - \frac15 x\right) \right) = \ln 5 + \ln \left(1 - \frac15 x\right) $$

then as the series for $\ln(1 - x)$ is

$$ \ln(1 - x) = -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} $$

we see that

$$ \ln(5 - x) = \ln 5 - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n5^n} $$

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**:

$\ln(1-u)=-\Bigl(u+\dfrac{u^2}2+\dfrac{u^3}3+\dotsm\Bigr)$
is a basic expansion.